# Which one of these is correct in use?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, usage, sentence-choice

Now, I am mixed-up over these sentences. I am looking for a good explaining from you. Thanks so much!

QA1

I didn't used to like opera, but now I do. (1)

I didn't use to like opera, but now I do. (2)

QA2

I usedn't to like opera. (1)

I didnt use to like opera. (2)

QA3

I used not to like opera. (1)

I used to not like opera. (2)

Comment: Does [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/used-to) help? (2:1) might be used by some people but would be regarded as _very_ informal. (3:2) could be better expressed as 'I used to dislike opera'.

Comment: It should be "I **am** mixed up over these sentences" or "I **have** mixed up these sentence", but "I have mixed up over these sentences" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Linguistics professor John Lawler has pointed out more than once on ELL / ELU that "nobody knows" whether you should write *didn't **use** to* or *didn't **used** to* in such contexts. Reason being that *no such distinction can be made in actual **speech***. It's worth looking at [this NGram usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=didn%27t%20use%20to%20smoke%2Cdidn%27t%20used%20to%20smoke&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10)

[image: NGram usage chart]

...which to my mind strongly suggests that *grammarians and pedants* favour ***use*** (perhaps because they think of it as an "unmarked infinitive" usage, I've no idea). But it seems ordinary people are more likely to think it should be ***used***, to reflect past tense ***did*** - and as the years have rolled by, that "populist" position has gradually gained traction.

Note that although the two written forms *appear* to be about equally common for several decades now, I'm pretty sure explicitly past tense ***used*** is in fact the more common "natural" usage today. That's because current usage figures will be somewhat skewed by citations from earlier text, plus older people still sticking to what they were erroneously taught by pedantic teachers in their youth.

---

You might think you could sidestep the issue by writing/saying *I **usen't** to smoke* - but this would be a mistake, since that form is rarely used today (and will normally be perceived as "stilted" or worse).